# How to create url-widget for a document with extra form fields programmatically with Echosign?

Tags: java, echosign

I have an application where I upload a PDF to echosign using its SOAP API. I wanted to know, How to add form fields at desired positions on the pdf programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is few months old, but in the past, I've used the java itext library (http://itextpdf.com/) to merge fields in an application into an updateable PDF file.
Basically, you start out with an updateable PDF template.  Then you clone the document and using the java itext library, you can stamp the clone file with the fields from your app.

Hope this helps!

Neo